# how to send component data as json to server?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

this is my setup:

```
<template>
    <div id="" style="min-height: 100px">
        <template v-for="(block, index) in blockList">
            <component :is="block"></component>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import TextBlock from './blocks/TextBlock.vue'
    import ImageBlock from './blocks/ImageBlock.vue'

    export default {
        data: function data() {
            return {
                blockList: ['text-block', 'image-block', 'text-block']
            }
        },

        props: {
            blocks: {type: Array}
        },
        // afterMount () {
        //     this.blocks.push(['text-block']);
        // },
        components: {
            TextBlock,
            ImageBlock
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

So just to test everything is working I added some components manually: blockList: ['text-block', 'image-block', 'text-block']

and everything renders fine on the page. However I will not be manually adding components but I will let user add them and user will be able to add any number of components. There will be more components then currently 2 I am using.

When I have added lets say 10 different components to the page and user presses Save button, how would I go about sending this data to the server? I can't just send blockList array to the server as that is just an array of strings.

What I want to do is to keep a track of all components that have been added and then with a push of button send to server a json with all components and their properties like if I had entered any text into a text component, or if I had uploaded an image into image component, I need all that data to be sent to server as well so I can recreate it when page is later reloaded for edit again.

So how can I do this as blockList: ['text-block', 'image-block', 'text-block'] wont do? How do I keep an array of components and all their properties and with push of button send this to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your components to support `v-model`. Change your `blockList` data structure to look something like this:

```
const blockList = [
  {
    component: "text-block",
    model: null,
    label: "Name"
  },
  {
    component: "text-block",
    model: null,
    label: "Address"
  }
]
```

Notice that each of the items in the `blockList` now has a `model` you can use to collect data from the component. Then, bind your component to the blocks model using `v-model`.

```
<component v-for="item in blockList" 
           :is="item.component"
           v-model="item.model"
           :label="item.label"
           :key="item">
</component>
```

Here is an example component implementation:

```
const TextBlock = {
  props:["value", "label"],
  template: `
    <div>
      {{label}}
      <input type="text" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" :value="value">
    </div>
  `
}
```

Now, each element in the `blockList` will contain the data collected from that component. When you want to save that data, iterate over the `blockList` and pull out the data you want to submit.

Here is a [working example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/LLJqeJ?editors=1010).

In this example, I'm not doing the work of submitting the data, you can probably work that out on your own. Nor have I implemented an ImageBlock component; I'm not sure how you want that to work anyway. But following the same pattern, you should be able to support `v-model` on the ImageBlock component and submit the data in the same way.

Comment: wow thanks, this is great answer. Can you clarify what happens when v-model="item.model" is run? since model=null when initialized, when does it become something else then null? Also what does this do: @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"?

Comment: @maxit `v-model` is a directive "a two-way binding on a form input element or a component." See the [documentation here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model). The code `@input=...` attaches an event handler to the `input` event of the `input` element and emits the current value of the input element. Since `v-model` by default listens for `input` events, `item.model` will be updated with the new value of the input element.

Comment: Ok I get it now, the model will get value that I input into the textbox, that is why this: return this.blockList.map(b => b.model) combined with this Collected Data: {{values}} gives me back the values I have entered. But here is the problem, I want to send to the server not only the values I have entered but also I type of component and any additional settings I may have defined inside that component, for example I may let user customize some settings for that component, width, height, etc etc.

So how would I loop through a blockList and pull each component and its data?

Comment: I would like to send a json to server that looks like this "blocks": { 'textblock': {value="what ever was entered into textarea", setting1: "10px", setting2: "true"

How can I do that?

Comment: @maxit How will you differentiate between text blocks?

Comment: I am not sure I need to do that, I will save each content block into a database with some information like what type it is (image, text, textarea, etc), perhaps save id of the block in question to be able to tell them apart if needed, save any additional information like settings and last save the value that was entered, for example image url, text input, textarea input, etc. Can you give me example how to loop through an array and pull all data I need from component and send it to server? I can pay you for this if needed, just give me your paypal. I need a solution :)

Comment: for some reason it only renders second component: Collected Data: { "text-block": { "setting1": "10px", "setting2": true, "value": "Streetaddress 3" } } any idea why? Otherwise great help so far, if you can just help me get it to render both components into json :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148650/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-maxit).